# Cannot find JPA CacheIndex Annotation in Glassfish 3.0.1

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, glassfish-3

What's wrong with my installtion of Glassfish v3.0.1. I cannot find the CacheIndex Annotation for JPA. Does EclipseLink 2.0 not contain this annotation? Or is it s.t. that's missing in the Eclipse Helios Plugin for Glassfish v3.

Thank you.

Comment: Any reason you are not using 3.1.2.2 instead of 3.0.1?

Comment: Well, i did not have time yet to update my machine and all the servers we have. But your question sounds like that CacheIndex is s.t. that's new?

Comment: I was bitten by a Weld bug that was fixed in newer versions.  I have no idea about CacheIndex.

Answer (score 0):

The `@CacheIndex` annotation is an EclipseLink specific annotation. So you won't find it in the JPA API out of the box. So I think you will have to add EclipseLink to the compile-time dependencies of you project.